# Why are glibc printf()-functions inconsistent about null pointer formatting?

Tags: c, printf, glibc, null-pointer

With glibc,

- If your program calls `printf("%s", NULL)`, you get `(null)`, but
- if your program calls `printf("%p", NULL)`, you get `(nil)`.

But why is this the case?

Note: This is not a question about the C language *standard*, where passing a null pointer for an `"%s"` specifier results in undefined behavior; I'm asking about glibc's choices specifically (and these values are [hard-coded](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/stdio-common/vfprintf.c) in the glibc sources).

Comment: Just because there are different outputs for different specifiers, that doesn't make it inconsistent. It's just hardcoded in https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/stdio-common/vfprintf.c

Comment: @Cheatah: You're kind of splitting hairs here (and about the title only not even the body of the question). It's inconsistent in the sense that a different term is used.

Comment: Likely because the code was added at two different times by two different people who used different words describing (roughly) the same thing. Also likely that code hasn't been revisited as any type of priority in many years. But good food for discussion.

Answer (score 1):

This is a question for Roland McGrath.

He added vfprintf.c as part of the initial commit of glibc on Feb 17, 1995. This initial version contains both "(nil)" and "(null)" hardcoded for these specific cases.  The only comment on this commit is "Initial commit".

https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/28f540f45bbacd939bfd07f213bcad2bf730b1bf/stdio/vfprintf.c

For more context, the use of "(null)" for strings was present in FreeBSD 4.4 since at least May 27, 1994, although there is no special strings for the `%p` format specifier:

https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd-src/commit/58f0484fa251c266ede97b591b499fe3dd4f578e

Comment: [This](https://www.linkedin.com/in/roland-mcgrath-07927a2/) Ronald McGrath? Also, that's more of a comment than answer, but +1.

Answer (score 0):

C standard.
7.1.4

> ¶1 Each of the following statements applies unless explicitly stated
> otherwise in the detailed descriptions that follow: If an argument to
> a function has an invalid value (such as a value outside the domain of
> the function, or a pointer outside the address space of the program,
> or a null pointer, or a pointer to non-modifiable storage when the
> corresponding parameter is not const-qualified) or a type (after
> promotion) not expected by a function with variable number of
> arguments, the behavior is undefined.

As the C standard does not specify what happens if programmer passes the NULL pointer using `%s` format specifier, above general rule applies.

IMO it is Undefined Behaviour and there is no inconsistency. Any program passing NULL to the `print` function using `%s` is invalid.

Comment: I think OP is more interested in the glibc behaviour, maybe I'm wrong but the behaviour defined in the standard doesn't seem relevant here.

Comment: @DavidRanieri it can be anything. If I port glibc to other platform I am free to do what I want in this case. The only question is why `%p` prints (nil) instead if NULL as nothing like `nil` does not exist in C

Comment: Well ... you can port or fork glibc, but then it is no longer glibc :) as pointed about by Cheatah the result is hardcoded and observable.

Comment: The fact that it's undefined behavior in the standard is immaterial - because I asked about glibc, not standard-compliance. I'll clarify this in the question.

Comment: @DavidRanieri: glibc is somewhat of a reference implementation when you're writing libc-compatible functions in other contexts (where using glibc is impossible/irrelevant). So its specific choices beyond what the standard specified are important.

Comment: @einpoklum I did not say otherwise